# Java - extend all JTextComponent subclasses - an OOP dark corner?

Tags: java, oop, multiple-inheritance, delegation

I developed a `class AutoCompleteTextArea extends JTextArea` and I'm using it for my javaScript console:

[image]

Problem is, I would hate to leave my class to only extend `JTextField`, and am looking for a way to make it more generally extend all `JTextComponent` subclasses, so that my code will be reusable  (as my implementation doesn't use any spacific capability of `JTextArea`, it seem like the right thing to do).

I tried using delegation and receive the `JTextComponent` implementation as a constructor argument, but that's not possible since I override `paintComponent()`.

The only other possibility I see is duplicating the code and extending each of the `JTextComponent` subclasses separately (seems like a poor idea to me).

If Java had multiple inheritence, I think I could come up with a solution, but without it it seems like an impossible thing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: May http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern help you?

Comment: What about making a decorator? Create a class that extends JTextComponent and composes one (in the constructor) and then delegates to it anywhere applicable.

Comment: As much as I understand (and as wikipedia states) decorator pattern requires `some groundwork is done at design time`. And since I'm not going to modify `JText*` classes source, I don't see how it can be acheived...

Comment: I think this is the wrong approach. The autocomplete stuff isn't intrinsic to a text area or anything else; it's something that builds off a chunk of text, e.g., it builds off of keyboard events, regardless of what's consuming those keypresses. You might want to check out implementations in things like jedit or the autocomplete component of rsyntaxtextarea, https://github.com/bobbylight/AutoComplete

Comment: I think it is very much intrinsic to the text component: 1. autocomplete suggestion are being context sensitive (in my case, I synthetically analyze the javaScript in order to autocomplete the current expression). 2. It messes with the text component's UI (for instance - drawing suggetion string - requires overriding protected methods) and event handling (KeyEvent consumption). Basically, it is just another way of editing the text component's content in a convenient way.

Comment: A good rule of thumb in OO design:  Don't use inheritance for something that can be done without inheritance.  Inheritance causes strong coupling, which creates problems like the one you're having now.  The only aspect of your autocomplete that requires extending a JTextComponent class is the drawing of the "proposed" text in light gray, which one could argue should not be light gray (which is both hard to read and looks like disabled text) but rather should be selected text (as most web browsers do it).

Comment: I would take your advice and implement it as an outside component. But if I still want it to be a greyd text (similar to the way chrome does it) - is there a way to listen to paint events on the text component and draw my string on top of it?